# How do you mock an abstract class containing an internal abstract method using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, moq, abstract

I have class `A` that I am unit testing a method on that takes class `B` as a parameter. Class `B` is what I am trying to mock out, and it is an abstract class. The class is similar to below.

```
public abstract class B
{
    internal abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

My unit test looks like.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ClassA_Add_TestSomething()
{
    var classA = new A();
    var mock   = new Mock<B>();

    classA.Add(mock.Object);

    // Assertion
}
```

I receive the following exception.

> Test method TestSomething threw exception:
>   System.ArgumentException: Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.  ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'DoSomething' in type 'Castle.Proxies.BProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

I can get around this by making the method virtual instead of abstract, but that is not what I want to accomplish with the API design. I have also tried providing it a implementation through `mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething())` to no avail. Is this possible with Moq, or am I going to have to create a concrete test class that derives from the abstract class B? I wanted to avoid creating concrete types, which kind of defeats some of the purpose of using a mocking or stubbing framework, or am I mislead here?

**Edit** I have discovered that if I make the method `public abstract` this issue does not occur. So I guess the real question is if this is even possible with an internal method when using InternalsVisibleTo and Moq.

Comment: Why cant you use mock.Setup ?

Comment: I receive the exception whether I use Setup or not. In my unit test, I don't care whether `B.DoSomething` has an  implemenation or not, though I understand why it would need one. It is possible I am not using `Setup` correctly, but what I had tried was pretty basic `mock.Setup(m=>m.DoSomething()).Callback(() => {});`

Comment: Consider carefully why you have an `internal abstract` method on a public class. Others will not be able to implement the abstract method because it is not visible to them. Perhaps this is what you want, although then I would recommend making the constructors internal as well so no one gets the idea that they could implement the abstract class.

Comment: +1 because I agree. It is component development (not UI though) where there is some internal communication for the components to all work together correctly (similar to a TabControl and its child Tabs). Except in my case it is barcode processing. I am actively rethinking the design though, to maybe find a better approach, but right now it is actually pretty decent even though I have this current caveat.

Comment: @mikez Will you move your comment to an answer so I can mark it as accepted? The solution in my case was to revise the design to be more easily tested concise.

Comment: @DavidAnderson-DCOM sure, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider carefully why you have an `internal abstract` method on a public class. Others will not be able to implement the abstract method because it is not visible to them. Perhaps this is what you want. Sometimes, given various design constraints, this is a valid approach. If your library is going to be consumed by others, I would recommend at least making the constructors internal as well so no one gets the idea that they could implement the abstract class.

Answer (score 6):

Moq relies on [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to implement its mocks. At runtime, a new assembly is created and loaded into your AppDomain by Moq (the name *DynamicProxyGenAssembly2* that appears in the exception message).

The issue is that this assembly **cannot access internal classes and members of your own code**, because they are not visible outside the assembly where you declared them.

A *workaround* is to mark your assembly with the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) and specify the name of the dynamically generated assembly :

```
[InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Remember however that this solution relies on an implementation detail, and might stop working in future versions.

Comment: This is helpful in general, but in my case InternalsVisibleTo is already appropriately applied. The issue is with Moq handles the internal method on an abstract type, specifically. The answer ultimately was as MikeZ had suggested, which was to rethink the design.

Comment: As @DavidAnderson-DCOM mentioned, this solution doesn't work in this case. I can confirm this in my own testing.

Comment: Used `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` with `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices` Then I was able to mock the internal class.